# SFTP Protocol Not Supported Issue in R

Tags: r

I'm having issues using the [SFTP functionality of this package](https://github.com/stenevang/sftp). Here is the issue I'm running into.

If I enter my credential information as such:

```
sftp_con <- sftp_connect(server = "sftp.name.com",
                          username = "username",
                          password = "password",
                          protocol = "sftp://",
                          port = 2222)

sftp_download("*")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
  Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Is there a way around this? If it helps, I'm on a Mac Book running this.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://github.com/stenevang/sftp/issues/10

Comment: @MrFlick Correct. Is that an issue?